# Simple "for loop" do not calculate the right numbers in C

Tags: c

I want to create a diagonal matrix with entries `diag[i][i] = 2/(2i+1)`.
Here is my code and I really do not see why it does not work. It has to be:
`diag[0][0]=2`, `diag[1][1]=2/3` and `diag[2][2]=2/5` for `l=2`. The fact that `a` has a different value as `diag[i][i]` is also confusing. 
Hope you can help me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    int l = 2;
    int i , p;
    double diag[l+1][l+1];
    int a;

    for (i = 0; i < l+1; i++)
    {
        p = 2*i + 1;
        printf("%d ", p);
        printf("\n");
        diag[i][i] = 2 * 1/p;
        printf("%d ", diag[i][i]);
        printf("\n");
        a = 2* 1/p;
        printf("%d ", a);
        printf("\n");
    }

}
```

Comment: This is like the most frequent FAQ of all time... `1/p` is done on `int` type, not floating point.

Answer (score 1):

this does not work as you wish

```
diag[i][i] = 2 * 1/p;
```

this does

```
diag[i][i] = 2.0/p;
```

p is an integer. You have to force floating division or you'll get 0 if p>1 or 1 if p=1

Comment: yes! my eyes were only looking on the right of the screen :)

Comment: I suggest `double p;` in the first place :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use `%f` format when printing double values, not `%d` as you have used.

Instead of `printf("%d ", diag[i][i]);`, use `printf("%f\n", diag[i][i]);`

Same goes for printing value of `a`, which should be declared as `double` (not `int`) if you want to compare its value to `diag[i][i]`.

Answer (score 0):

`1 / <any integer larger than 1>` is always `0`.

It's INTEGER DIVISION at work.

Answer (score 0):

This a classic problem with C. Which type is used for calculation?

With this line:

```
diag[i][i] = 2 * 1/p;
```

you expect a floating point result (i.e. a `double`) because the LHS (Left Hand Side) is a `double`. However, on the RHS (Right Hand Side) you only have `int`. So what happens is that the calculation `2 * 1/p` are done using the type `int`. When the calculation is done, the result is converted to `double`.

Doing the calculation `2/3` as `int` results in `0` as an `int` can't hold the result `0.6666`. The result `0` is then converted to `double`. So instead of getting the expected `0.6666` you get `0.0`.

To solve this you need at least one `double` in the RHS expression. That will force the calculation to be done in floating point. The easy way is:

```
diag[i][i] = 2.0/p;
             ^^^
             floating point

printf("%f ", diag[i][i]);
        ^^
        Use %f for print of floating point
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't understant why are you doing this.

```
diag[i][i] = 2 * 1/p;
```

It should be like that

```
diag[i][i] = 2 / p;
```

If you want that value of variable **a** to be equal to **diag[i][i]** then you should to declare this variable like double. And you should put that a is equal to diag[i][i] so:

```
double a;
a = diag[i][i];
```